# Evaluate the line integral $\int_C (x^2-y+3z)\;ds$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the line integral $\int_C (x^2-y+3z)\;ds$ where C is the line segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,2,1)$

So I did the following:

$$r(t)=(1-t)\langle 0,0,0 \rangle+t\langle1,2,1\rangle$$

$$r(t)=\langle 0,0,0 \rangle + \langle t,2t,t \rangle$$

So this means that $x=t$, $y=2t$, and $z=t$.  Which means $dx=1$, $dy=2$, and $dz=1$

So my integral then becomes:

$$\int^1_0 \left(t^2-2t+3t\right)\sqrt{1^2+2^2+1^2}dt$$

$$\sqrt{6}\int^1_0 t^2-2t+3t\; dt$$

When evaluated gives me the following solution:

$$\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Did I go about solving this correctly?

Comment: Distribute the square root I.e. multiply half with the square root

Comment: @AmerYR not sure I understand, but are you saying I should instead have as an answer $\frac{2\sqrt{6}-3}{6}$?

Comment: You went about it correctly, but your answer is not correct. Re-evaluate your definite integral.

Comment: @danielson ahh... I found the error.  Like AmerYR was saying, I needed to the distribute the square root!